# Deploying office 365 ProPlus and Project 2019 Volume Licensing

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-project

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

I'm running into some issues deploying both Office 365 ProPlus (Monthly) and Project 2019 Volume Licensed to workstations. Independently, each software package installs without error, but when I install ProPlus, THEN Project 2019, I get a "Blocking Application: Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus en-us" fatal error.

Reading https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer, I find that I should be able to do this, since this is a supported scenario. Office 365 Monthly is at version 1809, which is greater than the first version recognized at 2019 (version 1808).

However, I run into this additional note: "For Office 365 and Office 2019 products, all products installed on the computer **must be using the same update channel**". From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/update#update-channel-for-office-2019, I read "“PerpetualVL2019” is the only supported update channel for Office Professional Plus 2019 and Office Standard 2019. It's also the default update channel for volume licensed versions of Project 2019 and Visio 2019"

If I change the deployment channel for Project to "Monthly" (from PerpetualVL2019), isn't this just the same as if I were using "Project Online Professional" (the Office 365 flavour of Project), and not volume licensed? This scenario allows the software to be installed, but I'm not sure where it's at license-wise.

Any help, direction, current experience with deploying Office 365 ProPlus and some Volume Licensed 2019 components is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not need to change the update channel for Project 2019. I would like to know the detailed configuration.xml file you used for Project 2019 deployment and Office 365 ProPlus respectively. Would you mind to share them in your posting? Also make sure you have downloaded the latest Office Deployment Tool for the deployment https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117.

Answer (score 2):

The update channel doesn't affect your licensing status. It only determines the level of testing that patches must receive before the updates will be available. Your perpetually licensed Office software will only receive security updates and bug fixes, no new functionality will be made available.  The Office 365 products will receive security updates, bug fixes and feature updates. Your update channels must match because Office 2019 uses the Click-to-Run installer and has shared libraries with the rest of your Office 365 suite. If they weren't on the same schedule, your products would give conflicting information about which updates should be installed. More information is available in the Microsoft document you linked in your question: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/update